# How to set control to second cell of newly created row of datagridview

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I have the following requirement: as a new row is added to a dataGridview, the control(cursor) should be on the 2nd cell in edit mode. Please help. It work at the time of form load but what after operation on very first which added during form load.new row will add but the control will not move to the 2nd cell of that newly added row.

Comment: Pls show us what you've tried so far

Comment: its not working for me any alternate solution

Comment: Its only working for 1st row what about next rows

Comment: its work only for first row what about remaining rows of the datagridview